# SCSS compile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors, sass

I have recently started to see this error, and I cant work out what has caused it as I havent changed the css files recently[image]

Comment: Post your `RAILS_APP/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`. You mistakenly added some bad character in there.

Comment: Check encoding of your SCSS files.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539294/how-do-i-determine-file-encoding-in-osx

[Converting the encoding of a text file (Mac OS X)][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/151981/converting-the-encoding-of-a-text-file-mac-os-x

Comment: when i check my filetypes im getting `Paul-McGuanes-MacBook:stylesheets paulmcguane$ file -I application.css
application.css: text/x-c; charset=us-ascii
Paul-McGuanes-MacBook:stylesheets paulmcguane$ file -I icons.css
icons.css: text/x-c; charset=us-ascii
Paul-McGuanes-MacBook:stylesheets paulmcguane$ file -I admin.css.scss
admin.css.scss: text/x-c++; charset=us-ascii`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your SCSS file to UTF-8; if it contains any characters (â, in this case) outside the range of \x00-\x80 then it can't be implicitly converted from ASCII.

Any decent editor should be able to convert it to UTF-8, or failing that use `iconv`.

Of course, you can also just remove the offending character, but I presume it's there for a good reason.