# How do I determine the encoding of text if I already know what a sample should be?

Tags: r, character-encoding

I'm trying to PDF scrape a [list of physician names](https://www.chchealth.org/GetFile.aspx?FileID=283).  The file appears to be in mixed encoding.

When I copy/paste a single physician's name (page 51), I get this:

> Dandona, Suklesh 

If I paste just the jibberish part to a text file and try enca, I get:

```
enca -L none CHC_test.txt 
Universal transformation format 8 bits; UTF-8
```

Which ain't it.

The wrinkle here that makes this not a duplicate of [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539294/how-do-i-determine-file-encoding-in-osx) is that if I just view the file in a PDF viewer I can see the address.  It's (typing it out): `1601 Main St Suite 306`

So how do I convert the addresses in this file?  `enca` doesn't seem to take known text strings.  I guess I could run every single supported encoding through `iconv` programmatically and see if the result equals what I have typed out below.  Since R has an `iconv` interface I might do just that, but perhaps someone has a better solution?

I'm aware of the usual caveats about encoding: there's no way to know for sure, unicode is not an encoding, etc.  I have read Joel, I promise. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an encoding issue, you're dealing with an obfuscated PDF, which is likely a deliberate measure to keep people paying for databases of this information. This is one of the features of transporting our documents around the Interwebs as [programs in a Turing-complete language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript#The_language).

Your best bet is to render this to an image and then parse using OCR, which works nicely in my tests (using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert to 300dpi PNGs and parsing them using [cuneiform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CuneiForm_%28software%29) on Linux):

```
themel@kallisti: ~/so $ grep Street cuneiform-out.txt 
Adoue Street 
7930 Broadway Street Suite 
6516 Broadway Street Suite 
6516 Broadway Street Suite 
218 East House Street 
303 North Mckinney Street 
826 South Meyer Street
```

Comment: PDFs are Turing-complete?  Who knew?  Thanks for the guidance.