# Utf8 opengraph titles get mangled despite setting charset to utf8?

Tags: php, utf-8, facebook-opengraph

I'm using a php lib to retrieve the opengraph tags from a website https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph/blob/master/OpenGraph.php

```php
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogHIUNfu2vY';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/libs/opengraph/OpenGraph.php';

$graphObj = OpenGraph::fetch($url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($graphObj);
echo '</pre>';
```

This title is incorrectly retrieved as

```
[title] => HÃ¼sker DÃ¼ - I'll Never Forget You
```

It should be

```
[title] => Hüsker Dü - I'll Never Forget You
```

How can I retrieve the open graph tags in utf-8?

Comment: i'll bet this has to do with how the actual physical file is encoded. check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6146066/977083) to determine and change file encoding

Comment: ...and in a pinch, these quick and dirty helper functions have been known to save the day: [function.utf8-encode](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php), [function.utf8-decode](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

Comment: I don't know what the original encoding is, but I assume it is utf-8.  Also - the first helper function only converts from ISO-8859-1 chars to utf-8.  I don't think the original encoding is in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score -2):

```
$graph = OpenGraph::fetch($url);
$body = current($graph);
$description = utf8_decode($body['description']);
```