# determing server response encoding

Tags: encoding, sockets, character-encoding

not java specific, but when I say `OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();`
is there a way to determine stream's encoding charset?  or do I have to know encoding charset ahead of time to properly read it?  This is for arbitrary socket connection.

Comment: Don't you mean `InputStream`, not `OutputStream`? You're talking about reading so you must be dealing with an `InputStream`. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ways to detect text encoding, for example web browsers do that.
This is an implementation in Python([Universal Encoding Detector](http://chardet.feedparser.org/)) that might give you some help.
**Edit:**
Here is one for java: http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/
**Edit2:**
Here is another SO question: [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838)

Answer (score 0):

Streams do not have associated charsets.  They just pass around arbitrary data.  You have to know the data's charset ahead of time in order to interpret the data.