# recognize code page of input string

Tags: c#, character-encoding, codepages

How to recognize code page of input string, for example if I put something in Cyrillic it should return windows-1251 and when I put string in Chinese it return other code page etc

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file

Comment: It's not just related, it looks like the same question. The only difference is the source of the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an input from a textbox (windows forms) the string is a .Net string, [and is always in unicode (UTF-16)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx).

If you get the input from a Web form (aspx) page, the browser also sends the codepage with it. And .Net will make it unicode for you.

If you get the input from a file, [I wish you good luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file) ;-).