# How to determine a flat file in C#

Tags: c#

I wrote an application that search for a specific text in flat files. But the problem that i'm having is that my application end up reading non flat files like doc,docx etc. So i want to prevent this from happening. Is there a logic that i can use to determine if a file is flat file or not ?

By flat files i'm referring to files such as .log, .txt, .config, .cs, .vb etc.

Here is my code to read files :

```
string[] extension = txtExtension.Text.Split(';');

if (extension.Length == 1)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtDirectory.Text, "*." + txtExtension.Text.Trim(), SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    for (int append = 0; append < files.Length; append++)
    {

    }

 }
```

Comment: Define "flat". After you provided a formal definition for that you would be able to implement it yourself.

Comment: By flat file i mean a file without a hierarch. E.g .txt,.config, .log etc. I dont want to process files like .doc/.docx because they have files within them. E.g xmls withing them.

Comment: I found a solution on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910873/how-can-i-determine-if-a-file-is-binary-or-text-in-c

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote an application that search for a specific text in flat files.

I guess by "flat file" you mean a "[text file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file)". Even this concept is fuzzy, and there i[s no foolproof way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751191/how-to-detect-if-a-file-is-not-a-text-file-in-c-sharp/4751214) of deciding if a file is textual or binary, only some heuristics. You can restrict to some list of file extensions that you assume correspond to textual files, but even this is platform dependent and not 100% safe.

Comment: Is there a website that list all well known flat files ? Maybe i can start from there.

Comment: You have some conceptual issues. There is no standard distinction among flat-files and hierarchical files.