# To read a .txt File of a particular Encoding type in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, readfile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)

I have to read a (text) .txt file.But I don't know its encoding type.The encoding type may be

```
Encoding.ANSI
```

or

```
Encoding.Unicode
```

So my question is 'How can we know and read that a specific file is of particular encoding type?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\CreateAsciiFile.txt",true);
string LineText= sr.ReadLine();
System.Text.Encoding enc = sr.CurrentEncoding;
```

Check this answer it might help you : http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10077748/get-file-encoding.aspx

have look to this also : [Encoding Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xeez0yd1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In general - you can't. The StreamReader constructor has an builtin heuristic to guess the encoding if you don't provide it, which may be good enough for you, but that is not a 100% solution

Read this article of Joel Spolsky

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

to get more insights.