# Is there a way to detect the encoding of a stream in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, detection

I would like to know the way a stream or a string is encoded before converting it. If a string is not utf-8 it would be converted to utf-8.

Comment: Well, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file

Answer (score 1):

You could use the WinAPI function [`IsTextUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318672%28VS.85%29.aspx) which uses a heuristic to guess the proper encoding. Note that this can go [hilariously wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts).

The best way is not to accept streams without external information about their encoding, and failing that, internal information (such as a BOM, or a HTML meta-tag with encoding information).

Comment: Ok, but if I was only to detect that the stream is not utf-8, then I convert it to utf-8.

Comment: @marko True, in that case the above function will probably work quite well. As far as I see, most ambiguities are with UTF-16LE.

Comment: +1. See also [Raymond Chen on the subject of IsTextUnicode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx) and also [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)