# How can VS detect file encoding when we can't?

Tags: visual-studio, encoding

According to several answers here on SO, eg. [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file) it is not possible to retrieve the encoding of a file.

How does VS do it then? If I "Save as", and select "Save with encoding" it shows the current encoding of my file.

Comment: When Saving, VS (or any other Editor) _determines_ the encoding. Detection is needed when Opening a file.

Comment: Check if [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/7a9decde-25c1-439e-8110-212eed64f371/) is a solution to your problem

Comment: Yes, but when you start saving VS has **detected the current encoding** correctly. The question is how it does just that, not how it saves...

Comment: Im starting to think that VS isn't detecting anything and may be using the default system encoding for files that doesn't have a [BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1) or other kind of marker...

Comment: If there is no BOM, all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, the editor detects encoding by searching for byte order marks or charset tags. If neither is found in the current document, the code editor attempts to auto-detect UTF-8 encoding by scanning byte sequences. [VS Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e19z9c39%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If VS fails to convert any [byte sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) to valid unicode symbols, it opens file in default system character set. No magic realy.