# Date format for conversion in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-parsing

is there anyone there who can tell me what type of a date format is this '1110620'? And how can I convert this to a 'yyyy-MM-dd' format. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously it is the 20th of June, AD 111

Comment: Are you sure that's not `110620`?

Comment: It would help immensely if you already had some examples on both sides - for instance, did you obtain this `1110620` value today, and is it meant to represent today's date?

Comment: Reliably determining the format of data based on one sample and no further information is generally not possible, and basically the same problem as [detecting the encoding of a text(file)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/90956/21567).

Comment: Does anyone know what today is in Captain Kirks "stardate"? Rounding allowed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That would be [64374.2](http://trekguide.com/Stardates.htm). But only for Kirk's timeline. They have to be calculated differently for the NG stuff. Anyway it looks like "startdate" also includes time. ;-)

Comment: Can you post an example where you know both the number and the date it represents?

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParse("1110620", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    string r = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
else
    throw new Exception();
```

Comment: Good solution, checking for possible errors. Upvoted! :)

Comment: But why the assumption of InvariantCulture? You should loop through all cultures.

Comment: @Henk: What for? I'm sure there is no culture that will be able to parse it if invariant will be not.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
string dt = "1110620";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "yyyMMdd", 
                                  CultureInfo.CultureInvariant);
```

or you can try (not elegant but works)

```
        int start = dt.Length - 4;
        DateTime d = new DateTime(
            int.Parse(dt.Substring(0, start)),
            int.Parse(dt.Substring(start, 2)),
            int.Parse(dt.Substring(2 + start, 2)));
```

Comment: @Henk: Have you any other, non-joke ideas what format is represented?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I thought OP was wrong with date... but he confirmed it was correct. I don't know if my answer is what OP is searching for... really, don't know. :)

Comment: @abatishchev : if it's a Julian daynumber it means 17 Sep 1673.

Answer (score 0):

The above format seems to be - yyyMMdd. You can write c# method to convert it accordingly. Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the first 3 digits are an extension of a two digit year. Where 100 corresponds to the year 2000.

So the format was originally `yyMMdd` and or perhaps `(year-1900)*10000+month*100+day` which extends logically to years after 2000 by prefixing a `1`. This also preserves integer sorting order.

So to parse it you could:

```
day=input%100;
month=input/100%100;
year=input/10000+1900;
```

With this formula `1110620` corresponds to `2011-06-20`

But unless you explain what your example should mean, this is just speculation.

---

My first guess was that it might be days since a certain date, but this would put the origin at around 1000BC, which is unlikely.