# How to read in files into a UTF-8 Java app where the files are in different character encodings?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

My application is set up to support storing UTF-8 character encodings. I am reading files that I get from various other organizations which might be in UTF-8, latin-1, ASCII, etc. Do I need to do anything special to ensure that the files which have various character encodings are read into UTF-8 format correctly? e.g. do I need to figure out what character encoding the file is in and explicitly convert it to UTF-8?

Or is the following sufficient?

`Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:/file.txt"), "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have that wrong.  You don't read *into* an encoding, you read *from* encoding.  The encoding you provide as the second argument to `InputStreamReader` should be the *expected encoding of the source stream(file)*.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:/file.txt"), "<encoding_of_file.txt>");
```

Once the data is in memory, it is always UTF-16.  When you want to write the data (assuming you always want to write it as UTF-8), then you will use:

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("destfile"), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the reader the **encoding of the file**.

If your input can be in many different encodings, then you might have a problem: You cannot reliably detect an encoding, see [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)

When you want to support different encodings, you basically have three options:

- Store information about the encoding somewhere, such as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` in XML files. Unfortunately, not all file formats – such as "plain text" files – have such meta data.
- "Detect"/guess the encoding with various heuristics. This might sometimes go wrong.
- Ask the user. This is terrible user experience, because most users have absolutely no clue what encodings even **are**.

Comment: Just so I understand it better, what would happen if you said the encoding was UTF-8, yet it was latin-1? Does all of latin-1 fit into UTF-8 and match up correctly? Or must you absolutely always set the file encoding of the source?

Comment: @BestPractices: Some encodings are compatible, most are not. If a file is ASCII, but you read it as UTF-8, nothing bad happens (UTF-8 was designed this way). But if a file is Latin-1/UTF-8, but you read it as UTF-8/Latin-1, then you get this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake