# Encoding to be used while reading the sql file using apache FIleutilities

Tags: java, sql, file-io, encoding, apache-commons

I am reading the below line from an .sql file using Apache File Utilities.

> INSERT INTO tablename (MESSAGE) VALUE('transfer of **£**[%1] to the
>   following [%2]:');

but after reading i get the below:

> 'transfer of �[%1] to the following [%2]:'

**problem:** **£** is read in as  �

I am using the below Code to read the file line by line :

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8");
while (it.hasNext()) {
                lineCount++;
                line = it.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
```

Print Line shows as : transfer of �[%1] to the following [%2]:'

when i see the variable watch in Netbeans it shows that char as  **\ufffd**

Am i reading it with wrong encoding ?

Is there is any encoding i can use for SQL queries to be read ?

Comment: It's plausible there is an issue reading the file correctly. It's also plausible there's an error in *displaying* the value. How do you know the value is incorrect? How are you displaying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've selected the wrong encoding for your file. I was able to reproduce your issue by trying to read an ISO 8859-1 encoded file with your code example.

You need to determine the encoding of your text file and adjust your charset accordingly. E.g.

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, Charsets.ISO_8859_1.name());
```

Sadly, determining the encoding is [not something you can do automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file). You need to be explicitly told what the encoding is.

Comment: @Dunncan i agree with you duncan. is there is a way to identify the encoding ? Mine is a .sql file

Comment: @Wills No, as explained in my final paragraph, you cannot figure this out programmatically with certainty. Some programs can guess for you, but it's only a guess.

Comment: thanks for the help can you please let me know any resource which i can use to get the encoding corrected - if in handy ?