# How to detect Windows-1251 encoded characters

Tags: android, character-encoding, cyrillic

Is there a proper way to detect the `Windows-1251` encoded characters ?

IMO, unlike multiple-byte native characters, `Windows-1251` is an 8-bit character encoding, so it's impossible to distinguish it from other 8-bit native characters like `latin1`. If I am wrong on this, please correct me.

The first clue to me is `locale`, I take all the `non-ascii` characters as `Windows-1251` if the locale is `ru`.

Are there any better ways ?

UPDATE:

Here is the context of my question, there are some `Windows-1251` encoded characters in the `ID3` info of a MP3 files, I have to detect the `Windows-1251` encoded characters and then convert them to UTF-16 using `icu4c` , otherwise those `Windows-1251` encoded characters will represented unreadable on my system(`Android`). I deem maybe some of you have better ways.

Comment: What are you trying to detect this from?

Comment: Some MP3 files have Cyrillic characters in the ID3 Tags which encoded in Windows-1251.

Comment: So you want to be able to take an MP3 file and discern whether or not the ID3 tags are encoded in 1251?

Comment: I want to tell whether the ID3 tags are encoded in 1251. Then I can convert the 1251 to UTFs properly using icu4c. Cause some of the 1251 encoded characters is represented unreadable in my system(Android). Do I make myself clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reliable way to detect, when given as input an array of 8 bit characters, which 8 bit encoding has been used for those characters.

Comment: So using locale is actually a proper way ?

Comment: No. My machine does not use 1251 and your files will still contain 1251 encoded tags when you move the file to my machine.

Comment: I mean, if the locale is ru(Russian) then I treat the single byte non-ascii characters as Windows-1251. Because our target market is Russian  so I met the unreadable characters issue in some Russian MP3 files.

Comment: That's up to you. Of course, you may well encounter lots of mp3 files with UTF-8 tags.

Comment: @Alan You cannot reliably detect the code page of a file, you need to be told it along with the file. The only way to do it would be to build a really complex set of heuristics, which would be a lot of work to research, test, and otherwise make work correctly. Big problems come, for example, in distinguishing between ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252, where the differences are extremely minor. More information in this question: [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/90838).

Comment: I recommend asking the user to identify their file if it doesn't contain identifying information already. That's how almost all text editors do it, except the ones that guess wrong (like Notepad).

Comment: @CodyGray You're right, I can't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

The [`GetACP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070.aspx) function can be used to determine this. It returns the identifier of the ANSI code page that is currently active for the system.

The documented list of code page identifiers can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx). The one you're looking for is `1251`, which corresponds to the "ANSI Cyrillic (Windows)" code page.

Very simple to use from code; e.g. in C:

```c
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    if (GetACP() == 1251)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL,
                    L"Your system uses the ANSI Cyrillic code page.",
                    L"Code Page Detection",
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe you misunderstand my question due to my bad English. Actually, I have to differentiate the native characters to see if it's Windows-1251(Cyrillic) encoded, if so I'll convert them to UTF using icu4c. Do I make myself clear ?