# Problems with special characters in R-Studio under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, special-characters, rstudio

I just opened some R-Scripts I wrote on R-Studio under Windows 7 in Ubuntu and somehow all the special characters get substituted by question-marks.

Has anybody an idea why that could be and how to avoid it?Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it out.

In my Windows 7 distribution the system-wide default encoding was set to ISO-8859-1. R Studio saves files under Windows with the system default, as seen [here](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/encoding).
(Note that the default encoding on Windows7 might also differ from the above depending on your geographical region)

Now, R-Studio on Ubuntu opens files by default with UTF-8  which causes the described problem with special characters. So to avoid this either save the original script with UTF-8 before opening in Ubuntu...or open R-Studio on Ubuntu and go to:

-> File

-> Reopen with Encoding

and define the Encoding.

Note that therefore you will have to know the Encoding/codepage of the script which can be found out only on the original OS not by the file itself as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)