# ByteStrings, Text, and encoding in Haskell

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, io

I wish to grab an input text using the IO functionality of `Data.Text`.  My quandry has to do with encoding discovery.  That is, if I am not aware of the encoding of the text before-hand, how is the IO in `Data.Text` of any use at all in situations where the encoding of the text being read is different than the system locale setting?  Is there an encoding discovery mechanism somewhere in `Data.Text`?

I know I might get a bunch of responses that say "use `Data.ByteString`", but wasn't `Data.Text` created for the purpose of getting away from the use of `Data.ByteString` for reading text?

Also, if I must use `Data.ByteString`, does anyone know what happens when octets 0x80 to 0x9f are read?  Are they read in as expected like the rest of the input?  They are undefined in ISO-8859-1, and `Data.ByteString`'s IO seems to indicate that input is treated as if the source is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: *"Is there an encoding discovery mechanism somewhere in Data.Text?"* [No](http://stackoverflow.com/a/90956/1139697).

Comment: Where did you see something indicating that inputting a ByteString will treat the input as ISO-8859-1?

Comment: In the spec of [Data.ByteString]( http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html) - also present in its lazy and char8 variants - under the definition of hGetContents

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand that statement and I wonder if it's mistaken/obsolete. I would expect that opening the file in binary mode would lead to no encoding changes at all.

Answer (score 5):

You’ll want to use `ByteString` for reading bytes, and, for example:

```
decodeUtf8' :: ByteString -> Either UnicodeException Text
```

From `Data.Text.Encoding` to actually decode the raw data and handle any encoding errors. There is no predefined mechanism in `text` for guessing encoding, but you can try to decode multiple times, or use ICU’s character set detection facilities. Unfortunately, that functionality is not currently available in `text-icu`, so you’ll need to import it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  I was just wondering if there was something less clunky than that, but I suppose it will have to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the encoding in advance, I think using `Data.ByteString` and reading in binary mode is exactly the right thing to do. You should get the input data exactly as bytes including octets 0x80 to 0x9f.

`Data.Text` is the right way to represent something with a known encoding, or rather in decoded form, but if you can't do the decoding on read then I don't think it makes sense to use it at that point.

If your code can later learn or guess the encoding appropriately that's the right time to make the switch.

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if there was some way of getting around it, but I guess not.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that there's nothing to get around :-) ByteString is the right representation until you know the encoding.