# .NET Framework text encoding

Tags: .net, text, unicode, encoding

When .NET controls receive input from the keyboard and I output the code to a file (stream-write to it), is the content encoded in UTF-16 (Windows's default)? What about when I copy text from a UTF-32 database into .NET text controls, what is the result?

Comment: may be you read this ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file?rq=1

Comment: It is encoded into whatever Encoding you passed to the StreamWriter constructor.  Default is utf-8 without a BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise now that everything in the .NET Framework is in UTF-16 unless otherwise explicitly converted.