# Not able to read special character "£" using Streamreader in c#

Tags: c#, encoding

I am trying to read a character (`£`) from a text file, using the following code.

```
public static List<string> ReadAllLines(string path, bool discardEmptyLines, bool doTrim) 
{
   var retVal = new List<string>();
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || !File.Exists(path)) {
        Comm.File.Log.LogError("ReadAllLines", string.Format("Could not load file: {0}", path));
            return retVal;
   }

   //StreamReader sr = null;
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default));

   try {
     sr = File.OpenText(path);

     while (sr.Peek() >= 0) {
         var line = sr.ReadLine();

         if (discardEmptyLines && (line == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()))) {
            continue;
         }

         if (line != null) {
            retVal.Add(doTrim ? line.Trim() : line);
         }
      }
   } 
   catch (Exception ex) {
            Comm.File.Log.LogGeneralException("ReadAllLines", ex);
   }
   finally {
      if (sr != null) {
           sr.Close();
      }
   }

   return retVal;
}
```

But my code is not correctly reading `£`, It is reading the character as `�` please guide me what needs to be done to read the special character.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the file you are reading is not in Default encoding as you are opening it. You should open it with appropriate encoding, and it will work. This is a great read on the topic: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Probably, the file is an ANSI file, and is read like a UTF-8 file.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Actually it is read an ANSI file...

Comment: If you read a UTF-8 file as if it were ANSI, you would have two or three weird characters instead of a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `Encoding.Default` with `Encoding.GetEncoding(437)`

Comment: @Sara Then can you try 1252, 37, 1140?

Answer (score 1):

The file you are reading is not encoded the same as `Encoding.Default`.  It is likely UTF-8.  Try using UTF-8 for this particular file.  For more generic usage, you should see [Determining the Encoding of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file).

Answer (score 0):

Look like a encoding problem. Try creating your `StreamReader` with a UTF-8 (or Unicode) encoding instead of default.

`StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8));`

Answer (score 0):

Encoding information can be provided to stream reader in 2 ways.

1)Save your file with save as option and select the appropriate encoding option from dropdown in windows.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtAX1.png)
2)If your files are dynamic in nature use Encoding.GetEncoding() with StreamReader