# SmarterCSV and file encoding issues in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding, smartercsv

I'm working with a file that appears to have UTF-16LE encoding.  If I run

```
File.read(file, :encoding => 'utf-16le')
```

the first line of the file is:

```
"<U+FEFF>=\"25/09/2013\"\t18:39:17\t=\"Unknown\"\t=\"+15168608203\"\t\"Message.\"\r\n
```

If I read the file using something like

```
csv_text = File.read(file, :encoding => 'utf-16le')
```

I get an error stating

```
ASCII incompatible encoding needs binmode (ArgumentError)
```

If I switch the encoding in the above to

```
csv_text = File.read(file, :encoding => 'utf-8')
```

I make it to the `SmarterCSV` section of the code, but get an error that states

```
`=~': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

The full code is below.  If I run this in the Rails console, it works just fine, but if I run it using `ruby test.rb`, it gives me the first error:

```
require 'smarter_csv'
headers = ["date_of_message", "timestamp_of_message", "sender", "phone_number", "message"]
path = '/path/'
Dir.glob("#{path}*.CSV").each do |file|
  csv_text = File.read(file, :encoding => 'utf-16le')
  File.open('/tmp/tmp_file', 'w') { |tmp_file| tmp_file.write(csv_text) }
  puts 'made it here'
  SmarterCSV.process('/tmp/tmp_file', {
    :col_sep => "\t",
    :force_simple_split => true,
    :headers_in_file => false,
    :user_provided_headers => headers
   }).each do |row|
    converted_row = {}
    converted_row[:date_of_message] = row[:date_of_message][2..-2].to_date
    converted_row[:timestamp] = row[:timestamp]
    converted_row[:sender] = row[:sender][2..-2]
    converted_row[:phone_number] = row[:phone_number][2..-2]
    converted_row[:message] = row[:message][1..-2]
    converted_row[:room] = file.gsub(path, '')
  end
end
```

**Update - 05/13/15**

Ultimately, I decided to encode the file string as UTF-8 rather than diving deeper into the SmarterCSV code.  The first problem in the SmarterCSV code is that it does not allow a user to specify binary mode when reading in a file, but after adjusting the source to handle that, a myriad of other encoding-related issues popped-up, many of which related to the handling of various parameters on files that were not UTF-8 encoded.  It may have been the easy way out, but encoding everything as UTF-8 before feeding it into SmarterCSV solved my issue.

Comment: What happens if you use the built-in [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) class?

Comment: Same issue as using SmarterCSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add binmode to the `File.read` call.

```
File.read(file, :encoding => 'utf-16le', mode: "rb")
```

> "b"  Binary file mode
>        Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
>        sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
>        specified.

ref: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read

Now pass the correct encoding to SmarterCSV

```
SmarterCSV.process('/tmp/tmp_file', {
:file_encoding => "utf-16le", ...
```

**Update**

It was found that `smartercsv` does not support binary mode. After the OP attempted to modify the code with no success it was decided the simple solution was to convert the input to `UTF-8` which `smartercsv` supports.

Comment: This addresses the first issue I was having, but still causes the SmarterCSV issue:

`=~': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Added to the answer to address your second problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a way to specify binmode for SmarterCSV - the error has now changed to what I was originally getting in my `File.read` step: `ASCII incompatible encoding needs binmode (ArgumentError)`.

Comment: In the example in SmarterCSV it has this `f = File.open(filename, "r:bom|utf-8")`. perhaps change your write statement to `File.open('/tmp/tmp_file', 'w:bom|utf-16le')`

Comment: Nope, no luck.  Any reason why this code would work in a Rails console, but not just simply running the code as a Ruby program (subbing out the SmarterCSV gem)?

Comment: On the Ruby console you might need to specify the encoding, eg `ruby -E UTF-16LE program.rb`

Comment: Still no luck.  I'm going to just call it a day on this one.  Encoding can be unnecessarily frustrating.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you're willing to share the file, I'd be interested to have a go at trying it out (Would also like to know the answer!) Perhaps I can just use that first line you posted?

Comment: I can share a sample file definitely - appreciate the offer.  How do I go about doing that through Stack Overflow?  Also, is there a surefire way to determine the encoding of a file?  Perhaps it's as simple as me not having the correct encoding.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/ for sharing the file is a good way. Unfortunately detecting code pages can be difficult, you really need to know what the file was - check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Here's a sample file (same format as the ones I'm trying to read in and process): http://www.filedropper.com/psy-gentlemen-messages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77132/discussion-between-rots-and-avocadorivalry).

Comment: Thanks @Rots for all the help - I updated my question with the solution I ultimately used and some commentary!

Comment: @AvocadoRivalry Nice job! You can add that as an answer if you like, rather than an update. If you'd like me to do that let me know, as I know we discussed this in our chat :)

Comment: No problem @AvocadoRivalry it was great working on this with you. I have updated this answer with your solution. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're using a 'flat-file' style of storage and character encoding is going to be an issue on both ends (reading or writing).

I would suggest using something along the lines of `str = str.force_encoding("UTF-8")` and see if you can get that to work.