# File encoding incorrectly detected

Tags: php, ubuntu, encoding, file-encodings

On Linux server if user uploads a CSV file created in MS Office Excel (thus having **Windows 1250** [or *cp1250* or *ASCII* if you want to] encoding) all to me known methods of detecting the file encoding return incorrect **ISO-8859-1** (or *latin1* if you want to) encoding.

This is crucial for the encoding conversion to final **UTF-8**.

Methods I tried:

- cli

  - `file -i [FILE]` returning *iso-8859-1*
  - `file -b [FILE]` returning *iso-8859-1*
- vim

  - `vim [FILE]` and then `:set fileencoding?` returning *latin1*
- PHP

  - `mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($filename))` returning (surprisingly) *UTF-8*

**while the file is indeed in WINDOWS-1250 (ASCII)** as proves i.e. opening the CSV file in LibreOffice - Math asks for file encoding and selecting either of *ISO-8859-1* or *UTF-8* results in wrongly presented characters while selecting *ASCII* displays all characters correctly!

How to correctly detect the file encoding on Linux server (Ubuntu) (best if possible with default Ubuntu utilities or with PHP)?

The last option I can think of is to detect the user agent (and user OS) when uploading the file and it is *windows* then automatically assume the encoding is *ASCII*...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)

Comment: You need to tell the user which character set and encoding to use or let them tell you which the file uses. Anything else is incomplete communication and is therefore data loss. How would you know that it's not CP437 or ISO-8859-1? (If they are using Excel, why not let them upload an Excel file or HTML or Office 2003 XML? These would tell you internally which encoding is used.)

Comment: @TomBlodget Users can only upload CSV files but these are in 99.99% created in MS Excel. I just cannot rely on one encoding as there still is this 0.01%.