# Java IO with UTF characters

Tags: java, file-io, utf-8

I have a weird problem with files.

I intend to modify the timing of an `.srt` file, but writing the new file seems to be a weird task.

Here's a sample code I wrote:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class ReaderWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\E\\Movies\\English\\1960's\\TheApartment1960.srt");
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
                Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.srt");
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,
                Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        int data = reader.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char theChar = (char) data;
            writer.write(theChar);
            data = reader.read();
        }
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

This is an image from the original file:
[image]

However, the resulted file seems like:
[image]

I searched a lot for a solution but in vain. Any help, please.

Comment: How are you viewing the output? In Notepad++ or something like that? Could it be a font issue?

Comment: @JGFMK It's in IntelliJ IDEA. However, I opened it in notepad++ with the same result.

Comment: Could it be the original wasn't in UTF-8? - maybe some other charset? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/306125-What-is-encoding-of-an-srt-file

Comment: @JGFMK How can I choose the correct encoding?

Comment: The reason I mentioned Notepad++ is it's supposed to detect and show the encoding out of the box. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file - that gets mentioned here too - but also there is a java solution in the link - even though it's tagged C#

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh5kc.png

Answer (score 2):

First a few points:

- There is nothing wrong with your Java code. If I use it to read an input file containing Arabic text encoded in UTF-8 it creates the output file encoded in UTF-8 with no problems.
- I don't think there is a font issue. Since you can successfully display the content of the input file there is no reason you cannot also successfully display the content of a valid output file.
- Those black diamonds with question marks in the output file are [replacement characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) which are "*used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode*". This indicates that the input file you are reading is not UTF-8 encoded, even though the code explicitly states that it is. I can reproduce similar results to yours if the input file is UTF-16 encoded, but specified as UTF-8 in the code.
- Alternatively, if the input file truly is UTF-8 encoded, specify it as UTF-16 in the code. For example, here is a valid UTF-8 input file with some Arabic text where the code (incorrectly) stated `Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-16"));`:

  `يونكود في النظم القائمة وفيما يخص التطبيقات الحاسوبية، الخطوط، تصميم النصوص والحوسبة متعددة اللغات.`

  And here is the output file, containing the replacement characters because the input stream of the UTF-8 file was incorrectly processed as UTF-16:

  `���⃙臙訠���ꟙ蓙苘Ꟙꛙ藘ꤠ���諘께딠�����ꟙ蓘귘Ꟙ동裘꣙諘꧘谠����꫘뗙藙諙蔠���⃙裘ꟙ蓘귙裘돘꣘ꤠ���⃘ꟙ蓙蓘뫘Ꟙꨮ�`

Given all that, simply ensuring that the encoding of the input file is specified correctly in the `InputStreamReader()` constructor should solve your problem. To verify this, just create another input file and save it with UTF-8 character encoding, then run your code. If it works then you know that the problem was the that the encoding of input file was not UTF-8.