# Check if a file is a text file or a binary file using Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to check if a file is a plain-text file. I tried the code below:

```
function IsTextFile(const sFile: TFileName): boolean;
//Created By Marcelo Castro - from Brazil
var
 oIn: TFileStream;
 iRead: Integer;
 iMaxRead: Integer;
 iData: Byte;
 dummy:string;
begin
 result:=true;
 dummy :='';
 oIn := TFileStream.Create(sFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
 try
   iMaxRead := 1000;  //only text the first 1000 bytes
   if iMaxRead > oIn.Size then
     iMaxRead := oIn.Size;
   for iRead := 1 to iMaxRead do
   begin
     oIn.Read(iData, 1);
     if (idata) > 127 then result:=false;
   end;
 finally
   FreeAndNil(oIn);
 end;
end;
```

This function works pretty well for text files based on ASCII chars. But text files can also include non-English chars. This function returns FALSE for non-English text files.

Is there any way to check if a file is a text file or a binary file?

Comment: (Off-topic, but still rather important:) You really should replace your `result:=false` with `Exit(False)`. If you find that the file is not a text file at char 2, there is not really any need to keep investigating the remaining 998 chars...

Comment: "Is there any way to check if a file is a text file or a binary file?" In general, no. It is possible for the same file to be a valid text file and a valid binary file when interpreted in different ways.

Comment: I agree that there is no definitive answer wether a file is text or not. However, you might not scan for bytes higher than 127, but for 0 bytes (if (idata) = 0 then result:=false;) which might give you a better probability to identify non-text files. This ony applies for ANSI/ASCII/UTF files.

Comment: @AndreRuebel: Except that UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, and UTF-32BE text files often have plenty of nulls in them.

Comment: With some effort, it is possible to create an algorithm that makes the right guess in most cases. For instance, you can check if the file would be *invalid* in a particular encoding (then you know it is not a text file in that encoding). You can see if every second byte is null; then it is likely UTF-16. You can try to search for English words. And so on.

Comment: I'm sure what @AndreasRejbrand and DavidH say is correct.  Personally I would try a simple statistical analysis based on the frequency of occurence of carriage return (#13) and linefeed (#10) characters.  If they always appear together, I think it would be good sign that the file contains text.

Comment: @MartynA note, some text files only have a CR (#13) or LF (#10) as new line character (like macos or linux text files)

Answer (score 1):

> You can't detect the codepage, you need to be told it. You can analyse
> the bytes and guess it, but that can give some bizarre (sometimes
> amusing) results. I can't find it now, but I'm sure Notepad can be
> tricked into displaying English text in Chinese.
>
> It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding
> it uses. You can no longer stick your head in the sand and pretend
> that "plain" text is ASCII. There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text.
> If you have a string, in memory, in a file, or in an email message,
> you have to know what encoding it is in or you cannot interpret it or
> display it to users correctly.

That's the first answer from here :
[How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)

You also should figure out any binary file can be a text in an uncommun encoding.
Also, binary files encoded in Base64 will just bypass any test you will think of, as it is by definition a text representation of a binary stream.