# How can I write a non-latin1 character into an exif tag using python?

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-imaging-library, piexif

As part of an app using Pillow, I want to update exif for a bunch of photos, including artist names, titles, etc.
So far, I've been using piexif to do so. However I ran into an encoding problem:

```py
import PIL.Image
import piexif

img = PIL.Image.open("photo.jpg")
exif_dict = piexif.load(img.info["exif"])
exif_dict.get("0th").update({
        315: "Lebœuf",  # ExifTag for "Artist"
    })
img.save("photo.jpg", "jpeg", exif=exif_dict)
```

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0153' in position 3: ordinal not in range(256)`

Encoding and its errors are a nightmare, one life will not suffice for me to grasp only the spirit of it. I understand that the character `œ` is not part of the latin1 encoding, which piexif uses without control over it. However, if I add the exif tag manually on, say, Windows 10 explorer, I can successfully add that character and even retrieve it through `piexif.load()`. My understanding is such as it seems not necessary to impose the latin1 encoding? Is there a workaround or another module I could use?

Comment: In a classic fashion, after a couple days struggling it's only after posting the question that I find the workaround I was looking for:
```py
exif_dict.get("0th").update({
        315: "Lebœuf".encode(),
    })
```
This does work. The error is not thrown and the exif shows the correct character. I don't post this as an answer for the reason that I am still unsure why this works, being so little knowledgable in the matters of encoding. Hope it helps my neighbour, however.

Comment: Related: [Python's exif module and Umlauts in JPEG Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65720067/)

Comment: You can add the solution as an actual answer (and even mark it as accepted).