# Best practice to determine the codepage of an unkown file? (with Progress-4GL Openedeg)

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, codepages

What is the best way to identify the codepage of a file?
I hoped i can use [DetectInputCodepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa740986(v=vs.85)) but i dont know how to implement it with progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what led you down that rabbit hole - the link you provided led to outdated documentation for Internet Explorer.

However. This problem is non trivial. See https://community.progress.com/s/article/000057930

Also

[How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file)

Based on the answer above (on Stackoverflow) you can download the mentioned Nu-package and extract the dll (using any zip-tool).

Add the ude.dll-file to your assemblies and then you can do like this (error checking etc missing in this example):

```
USING Ude.*.
USING System.IO.*.

DEFINE VARIABLE fs  AS FileStream          NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE ude AS CharsetDetector NO-UNDO.


fs = NEW FileStream( "c:/temp/test.txt", FileMode:Open).
ude = NEW CharsetDetector().

ude:Feed(fs).
ude:DataEnd().

IF ude:Charset <> ? THEN 
    MESSAGE SUBSTITUTE("Charset &1, confidence &2", ude:Charset, ude:Confidence) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
ELSE 
    MESSAGE "Failed" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

fs:Close().

DELETE OBJECT fs.
DELETE OBJECT ude.
```